# Where to place adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); when using Volley

Tags: android, json, arraylist, adapter, android-volley

This code runs fine, displaying my JSON response into an Arraylist. The problem is, that each time I click on the button to display the list again, it simply duplicates the previous JSON response, resulting in a list of repeated results.

How can I have it refresh the arraylist every time I click on the button, removing all of the previous results? Do I need to place another notifyDataSetChanged? if so, where?

Details.java code:

```js
public class Details extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = Details.class.getSimpleName();
    String url="removed";
    private Button ShowDetailsButton;
    private Button AddDetails;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<LoadUsers> mList = new ArrayList<LoadUsers>();
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.studio_student_view);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, mList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        ShowDetailsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_details);
        AddDetails = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_details);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        ShowDetailsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Creating volley request obj
                JsonArrayRequest studentReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                                hidePDialog();

                                // Parsing json
                                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                    try {

                                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                        LoadUsers details = new LoadUsers();
                                        details.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));
                                        details.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                        details.setEmail(obj.getString("email"));
                                        details.setPhone(obj.getString("phone"));

                                        // adding 
                                        mList.add(details);

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }

                                // notifying list adapter about data changes
                                // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hidePDialog();

                    }

                });

                // Adding request to request queue
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(studentReq);
            }

        });

    }
    public void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }
}
```

CustomListAdapter.java code:

```js
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<LoadUsers> usersItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<LoadUsers> usersItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.usersItems = usersItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return usersItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return usersItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView email = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvemail);
            TextView phone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvphone);


            // getting user data for the row
            LoadUsers m = usersItems.get(position);

            // thumbnail image
            thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

            // title
            title.setText(m.getTitle());

            // email
            email.setText("Email: " + String.valueOf(m.getEmail()));

            // phone
            phone.setText("Phone: " + String.valueOf(m.getPhone()));

            return convertView;

    }

}
```

Comment: Add `mList.clear();` right above the comment line `// Creating volley request obj` or right above the line `// Adding request to request queue` :)

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mistake:**

Data is getting duplicated because you are not clearing ArrayList having previous sets of data.

**Solution:**
Clear the ArrayList before making an API call. In your case, this should be very first line in button click listener code!

```
// clear collection 
mList.clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add `mList.clear()` after `public void onResponse(JSONArray response)`
also you could use `mList.addAll()` method to add all the elements in the adapter and notify once, otherwise if you use `mList.add()` you will be notifying each time a single item is added.

Note that notifying is done internally.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. It worked!

Solution:

```js
public class Details extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = Details.class.getSimpleName();
    String url="removed";
    private Button ShowDetailsButton;
    private Button AddDetails;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<LoadUsers> mList = new ArrayList<LoadUsers>();
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.studio_student_view);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, mList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        ShowDetailsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_details);
        AddDetails = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_details);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        ShowDetailsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
          
          mList.clear();

                // Creating volley request obj
                JsonArrayRequest studentReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                                hidePDialog();

                                // Parsing json
                                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                    try {

                                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                        LoadUsers details = new LoadUsers();
                                        details.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));
                                        details.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                        details.setEmail(obj.getString("email"));
                                        details.setPhone(obj.getString("phone"));

                                        // adding 
                                        mList.add(details);

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }

                                // notifying list adapter about data changes
                                // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hidePDialog();

                    }

                });

                // Adding request to request queue
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(studentReq);
            }

        });

    }
    public void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We have two approach here,

1. you Want to clear all the data and update the list completely.
2. You want to add some new data to list and show old data + new data

Approach 1:

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
    hidePDialog();
    // CLEAR YOUR OLD DATA HERE
    mList.clear();
    // Parsing json
    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
    try {
        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
        LoadUsers details = new LoadUsers();
        details.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));
        details.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
        details.setEmail(obj.getString("email"));
        details.setPhone(obj.getString("phone"));
        // adding 
        mList.add(details);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
  // notifying list adapter about data changes
  // so that it renders the list view with updated data
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

By following this approach your list become renew again.

Approach 2:

you just want to add new data and you want to show an animation for new added items.

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
    hidePDialog();
    // MAKE A NEW LIST HERE AND ADD NEW DATA TO IT
    private List<LoadUsers> mListNewItems = new ArrayList<LoadUsers>();
    // Parsing json
    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
    try {
        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
        LoadUsers details = new LoadUsers();
        details.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));
        details.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
        details.setEmail(obj.getString("email"));
        details.setPhone(obj.getString("phone"));
        // ADD NEW DATA TO NEW LIST 
        mListNewItems.add(details);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // IMPORTANT TASK SHOULD DONE HERE
    // Get Old Size Of the List before adding new data to notify new inserted items
    int oldSize=mList.getSize();
    // here we check whether we have such a data in our list. if we had, we dnt add that, otherwise add new data to our list
    for (int i=0;i<mListNewItems.size();i++){
    if(!mList.contain(mListNewItems.get(i))){
        mList.add(mListNewItems.get(i));
    }
    }

    //check how many new items added
    int numberOfNewItems=mList.getSize()-oldSize;

    // Here you should use notifyItemRangeInserted instead of notifyDataSetChange as it is less time consuming than notifyDataSetChange and also it let you to show animation for new added items.
    adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(oldSize,numberOfNewItems);
  }
```